# getting os name, ip address, mac address in java

Tags: network-programming

How can I get OS name, IP Address, and Mac Address of remote host in same local area network using java.I have tried arp -a and nmap -O but it's not reliable . It does not work on windows.

Comment: You first need to have a reference to the other host. You must have either the IP address, or DNS name, or MAC address if it is in the same LAN. If you have none, you cannot even begin.

Answer (score 0):

Get OS name:

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

Get IP:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

Not sure what you mean by 'Mac Address'